# Filter a pandas dataframe based on dates and groupby

Tags: pandas, filter, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date    group   File1   File2   Begin Date  End Date
4/28/2014   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
4/29/2014   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
4/30/2014   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
5/1/2014    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
5/2/2014    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/22/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/23/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/26/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/27/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/28/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/29/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/30/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
2/2/2015    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
2/3/2015    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
2/4/2015    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
2/5/2015    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
2/6/2015    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
8/25/2014   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/26/2014   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/27/2014   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/28/2014   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/29/2014   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
9/2/2014    B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/7/2015    B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/10/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/11/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/12/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/13/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/14/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/17/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/18/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/19/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/20/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
```

Its actually a much larger dataframe with more groups.  I have shortened it for display purposes.
I am trying to filter the dataframe on the date columns as follows:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby(['group','File1', 'File2']).df['Date'] >= df.groupby(['group', 'File1', 'File2'])['Begin Date']
```

The output should be as follows:

```
Date    group   File1   File2   Begin Date  End Date
5/1/2014    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
5/2/2014    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/22/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/23/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/26/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/27/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/28/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/29/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
1/30/2015   A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
2/2/2015    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
2/3/2015    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
2/4/2015    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
2/5/2015    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
2/6/2015    A   CC2015H CC2015K 5/1/2014    2/2/2015
8/29/2014   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
9/2/2014    B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/7/2015    B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/10/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/11/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/12/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/13/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/14/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/17/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/18/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/19/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
8/20/2015   B   ZC2015U ZC2015Z 8/29/2014   8/14/2015
```

Bonus question:  I would like to filter by Begin Date and End Date i.e. keeping the group by criteria

```
df['Date'] >= df['Begin Date'] & df['Date'] <= df['End Date']
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions in advance.

Comment: first of all convert the date columns into a datetime object with something like `df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`. This change opens up as lot of options.  Also, if you can put the dataframe a stext instead of pictures, it would be easier to help.

Comment: I have posted it as text as requested.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have tried converting it to datetime object and got the following error: TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'SeriesGroupBy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the need for `groupby` here because you are not aggregating anything (min, max, sum, count, etc.) from each group.

`between` is what you are looking for:

```
df[df['Date'].between(df['Begin Date'], df['End Date'])]
```